# What is the best Addons location?

Tags: add-on

**Blender 2.80**
Hi, looking for info on best practices for Addons.
**What are the benefits of installing to "Roaming" vs User and are both path location needed?**
I would like to have Stable and Beta version access Paid Addons. (FLIP Fluids, etc.)

**USER**
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\

**SYSTEM**
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\